# Display fields before dynamically adding with cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I have a form and i am using `cocoon gem` to add extra fields if the user requires. As it stands, its displays `add educations link` and then the fields appear, I would like to have the fields present in the form and then if required, users clicks `add education link` to render the fields. Other than that its all working fine, the models are all set up properly, but can't figure this out.

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :bio %>
  <%= f.text_area :bio %>

  <%= f.label :university %>
  <%= f.text_field :university %> <br>

  <%= f.label :course %>
  <%= f.text_field :course %> <br>

  <%= f.label :finishedDate %>
  <%= f.text_field :finishedDate %> <br>

  <div id="educations">
    <%= f.fields_for :educations do |education| %>
      <% render 'education_fields', f: education %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add education', f, :educations %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

_education_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.label :university %>
  <%= f.text_field :university %> <br>

  <%= f.label :course %>
  <%= f.text_field :course %> <br>

  <%= f.label :finishedDate %>
  <%= f.text_field :finishedDate %> <br>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove education", f %>
</div>
```

profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @profiles = Profile.all
  end

  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile = educations.build
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.create(profile_params)
    redirect_to profiles_path
  end

  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

  end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile.update(profile_params)
    redirect_to(profiles_path(@profile))
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, educations_attributes:[:id, :university, :course, :finishedDate, :destroy])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form shows a profile, with all it's existing educations. So if you want to show the fields for an education by default, add an education before rendering the form.

So, in your controller, where you do something like

```
@profile = Profile.new
```

you can build an initial education so it will show up in the form:

```
@profile = Profile.new
@profile.educations.build
```

Comment: I updates the controller and placed the fields within the form, but still getting an error `undefined local variable or method `education' for #<ProfilesController:0x007fd7d2ca43e0>` . I updated my question above to show how i done it.

Comment: You wrote `@profile = educations.build`, it should be `@profile.educations.build`: build a new education, on the association `educations`, of the new `@profile`

Comment: I edited as you said using @profile.educations.build, but still get an error undefined method `university'

Comment: Now you are already in the view! (I guess) Progress ;) If it worked for existing elements, I have no idea why it should not work when rendering (with the code you show here). My best guesses: 1) `university` is a lookup-field??? 2) there is no field called `university` (check your spelling) ???